# rails: making link_to method send remote request as JSON type, not JS type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rest, hyperlink

I have a link_to method that seems that gets interpreted as JS,
whereas I want it to be JSON.

This,

```
<%= link_to("Destroy", tour_event_path(tour, result), :id => 'delete_event', :remote => true, :method => :delete, :html => {:'data-type' => 'json'} )%>
```

Results in

```
Processing by EventsController#destroy as JS
```

What I want is

```
Processing by EventsController#destroy as JSON
```

I added a `, :html => {:'data-type' => 'json'}` as mentioned in another SO answer, but no luck.

I'm on rails 4. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to("Destroy",tour_event_path(tour, result,:format => :json ), id: 'delete_event',remote: true,method: :delete )
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your `link_to` like below :

```
<%= 
  link_to(
    "Destroy",
    tour_event_path(tour, result),
    id: 'delete_event',
    remote: true,
    method: :delete,
    data: { type: 'json' }
  )
%>
```